# Array scanning twice?

Tags: c, arrays, input, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int array[1][1];
   for (int x = 0; x < 2;x++)
   {
     printf("x%d\n",x);
     for (int y = 0; y < 2;y++)
     {
       printf("y%d\n",y);
       scanf("%d\n",&array[x][y]);
     }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to scan array elements to start a matrix calculator. The code takes 5 numbers as input not 4. After x0 and y0, it takes two numbers and idk why. I posted the output.

```
x0
y0
1
1
y1
1
x1
y0
1
y1
1
```

Comment: A 1x1 array can only contain one value. That's a variable, not an array. This cannot hold four entries like you're asking it to, that's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user3121023 it worked! thanks!

Comment: @tadman shouldn't it hold 4 elements? because if the count starts at one then it an array[1] would hold two values.

Comment: That's not the max index, that's the number of elements *total*.

Comment: Q: Shouldn't it hold 4 elements?  A: NO!!!!!!!.  `a[2][2]` holds four elements.  `a[1][1]` holds exactly *ONE* element!  You're confusing array *size* with array *index*...

Comment: Your array indexing is out of bounds.

Comment: When i print the elements in questions, it prints out 4 elements tho. How?

Comment: That is because the loops **tell** it to print 4 elements. That does not generate more elements than do exist. That's how C is. It doesn't protect you.

Comment: Q: When i print the elements in questions, it prints out 4 elements tho. How?  A: [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  It might *appear* to work ... even though you FAILED to correctly allocate the memory, and you MIGHT (sooner or later) crash with an access violation.

Comment: Undefined behaviour sometimes translates to "works on my machine". If you had other variables in memory after that array, as you would in a non-trivial program, you'd discover this code stomps all over those values when you write out of bounds. Just because it compiles and appears to work doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: @tadman it's still an array even if it only has 1 element

Comment: `scanf("%d\n",&array[x][y]);` --> `scanf("%d",&array[x][y]);`  Drop `'\n'`.  '\n'` looks for 0 or more white spaces.

Comment: @M.M Technically, yes, but in practice it's pointless and is just an unusually expensive variable. `int x[1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1]` is valid but also completely ridiculous.

Comment: @tadman `int x[1][1][1]...[1]` is at least a good exercise of _5.2.4.1 Translation limits_.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   // Define a 2x2 array
   int array[2][2];

   for (int x = 0; x < 2;x++)
   {
     printf("x%d\n",x);
     for (int y = 0; y < 2;y++)
     {
       printf("y%d\n",y);
       scanf("%d", &array[x][y]);
     }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Where `array[n]` has indices of `0`..`n-1`, where if `n=1` you have only one valid index.

Comment: The `printf` is a prompt for input, so I don't see why the prompt should come after.